# Laravel duplicated view after selecting dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem with my Laravel view. I am getting the desired data through ajax and I can also show that data in my view. However, I found that whenever I select something in my dropdown then the data appears, but the overall layout gets duplicated. I see my console and find that inside the table I have another layout created after selecting something with the dropdown. I have my code here please take a review of it.

```
<select>`enter code here`
        @foreach(App\StudentsClass::all() as $class)

                <option id="class{{$class->id}}" value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->class_name}}</option>

        @endforeach
        </select>

        <table id="studentsData" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list-search">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>Attendance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                @foreach($students as $student)
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{$student->id}}</th>
                    <td>{{$student->student_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->first_name}} {{$student->last_name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="gender">
                                <option>Present</option>
                                <option>Absent</option>
                                <option>Leave</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
                    @endforeach
        </table>
        <a class="fas fa-folder-open btn btn-success float-right mb-4 mr-2"> Save</a>
    </div>





    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            @foreach(App\StudentsClass::all() as $class)
            $("#class{{$class->id}}").click(function () {
                var classes = $("#class{{$class->id}}").val();
                $.ajax({

                                    url: '{{url('/students/attendance')}}',

                                    type: "GET",

                                    dataType: "html",
                    data: 'class_id=' + classes,

                    success:function(response) {

                                        // console.log(response);
                        $('table[id=studentsData]').html(response);

                    }

                     });
            });
            @endforeach
        });
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what data you return from the `/students/attendance` url?

Comment: I get data from data url is student row id, student id and student name but after getting this data successfully i everytime just see my layout gets duplicated and something weird . And i see that in console is that i have the whole layout inside my table but in my code i dont have something like that

Comment: Another thing i noticed is that if i removed that url then my code still working the same

Comment: I really dont know whats happening behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without knowing exactly that is returned by the ajax call -- but it sounds like you may be returning the either a full view (Everything from `<html> to </html>`) and inserting it into the table ... or the full html markup for a table, creating new nested tables on each ajax call.

Can you share the result of your ajax call? (What you see with console.log(response); )

Also, I don't think this is related but noticed a few things you could do to your code to simplify.  For example, Id suggest changing your dropdown's structure a bit and giving it an ID like so ...

```
<select id="class_select">
    @foreach(App\StudentsClass::all() as $class)
        <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->class_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And then rather than looping through each class and adding dedicated function, you could adjust your javascript to find the class ID and trigger the ajax call each time the dropdown is changed.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#class_select').change(function(){
            var class = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{url('/students/attendance')}}',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                data: 'class_id=' + classes,
                success:function(response) {
                    // console.log(response);
                    $('#studentsData').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps!  If we could see what the ajax call returns I think we could give a better answer.

Comment: From ajax in the console i am returning the students data which is desired but when i apply it to the view then it duplicates my full page layout.. I apply your code but same result

Comment: And also when ever i just run this console.log(response); then in the console i can see the right table and i see what i needed